# Paired or unpaired tests after using propensity score matching

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, paired-data, propensity-scores, matching

I used propensity score matching in one of my studies to reduce the effects of confounding.
Although some authors have suggested that methods of inference appropriate for independent samples can be used for assessing the statistical significance of treatment effects when using propensity-score matching, others recommended using statistical methods for paired samples (e.g., a paired t-test).

Can someone help me determine the most appropriate method, and if the data should be considered 'dependent/paired,' how to control for that in, for instance, correlation and mediation analyses? So is the data, after PSM, considered as dependent?

Comment: Voting to close because the details you provide in comments are very different than the actual question. I believe propensity matching is the opposite of what you should be doing in this analysis and multivariable modeling is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a test for paired samples because a well-done propensity match should produce pairs with significant intra-cluster correlation. Consider the probability model for response:

$$ Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \dots + \beta_p X_p + \epsilon$$

where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and $X_1$ is the covariate-of-interest (meaning you want a well controlled comparison for the expected difference in $Y$ comparing groups differing by 1 unit of $X_1$ holding all other $X_{2, \ldots, p}$ constant - that is the interpretation of $\beta_1$.

A paired sample could be obtained by matching each of $X_{2, \ldots, p}$ so that a sample of dyads have $Y_{1} - Y_{2} = (X_{1,1} - X_{1,2}) + 0 + 0 + \ldots + \epsilon_{1} - \epsilon_{2}$ where each 0 reflects a difference of equal values in pairs for $X_2$ to $X_p$. Propensity matching responses based on $X_2$ to $X_p$ essentiall ensures that $E((X_{2,1} - X_{2,2})\beta_2 + \ldots + (X_{p,1} - X_{p,2})\beta_p ) = 0$ so the variables can be treated like blocks and the error in response is minimized.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply. But it's still not clear to me how I can account for the "intra-cluter correlation" due to the matching in, for instance, a correlation analysis?

Comment: @ManuelLeitner can you back up and explain how you needed to perform propensity matching to do a "correlation analysis"? Are you aware the null hypothesis of a t-test is equivalent to the null hypothesis of a bivariate correlation test?

Comment: I divided individuals into 2 groups for my study based on MRI parameters: 'brain healthy individuals' and 'individuals with signs of pathology.' However, these two groups differed in age, which is why I wanted to eliminate the influence of age from the groups by performing propensity score matching to now have comparable groups in terms of age. Now, I want to conduct several analyses, including correlations between age and MRI parameters. However, I was unsure whether normal Pearson correlations are now permissible because I am working with a matched dataset??